# hsqldb select query really slow

Tags: hsqldb

I use hsqldb and I have constructed a database with a table that contains 10.000.000 records. It takes about 15min to construct this table. Then in another program that needs these data, I try to read them. I thought that reading them in groups of 100.000 would be faster. So I execute this query:

```
rs = st.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM PATIENT WHERE pid>="+start+" AND pid<="+end+" ;");
```

where start and end define the group I want to read each time.

I have made an index on pid but query execution is still very slow. Actually it's been running for 24 minutes and has fetched the first 24 out of 100 groups. Is this normal? What else can I do?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

It is a good idea to select in groups of 100000. You can verify that your query is using the index by executing this statement with your query:

```
EXPLAIN PLAN FOR SELECT ...
```

If the query is indeed using the index, you can speed up selection by defining

```
SET TABLE PATIENT CLUSTERED ON (PID)
```

or define PID as the primary key

You should also look at increasing the cache size of the database, or increasing the nio file usage limit, or other tweaks discussed in the Guide. Use the latest HSQLDB jars from http://hsqldb.org/support/